# Annotation Google Chart error

Tags: javascript, charts

Who knows, what's going wrong with Google Annotation Charts? It doesn't work right now. I get

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of null
```

In my console. This error in google library, not in my code.

Answer (score 1):

I think Google is updating the Annotation Chart API

Testcode: https://jsfiddle.net/lecaoquochung/dsmgL9wj/15/

or Google Document page
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotationchart

[image]

P.S. I met the same error today (20160229) with the testcode above (It's runnning up to yesterday and I haven't fixed anything with the code. Keep updating)

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of null 
O
(anonymous function)
e 
google.a.c.Xc 
google.a.c.Oa 
google.a.Oa 
(anonymous function)
```

Update 20160301: Google has updated chart package to ver 44

```
google.charts.load('44', {'packages':['annotationchart'], 'language': 'ja'});
```

Testcode: https://jsfiddle.net/dsmgL9wj/17/ (Annotation Chart version 44)

Answer (score 0):

The workaround is to explicitly specify previous version of the API to load instead of using current:
    google.charts.load('current', {
            'packages': ['annotationchart']
          });

Instead of current use 43

```
google.charts.load('43', {
        'packages': ['annotationchart']
      });
```